# Javascript Collapse HTML - My code isn't working, can you see any errors?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so here's my code, trying to make it so that when a button is clicked with onclick="contactChange", etc, it will make a display block invisible:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload; {
        var contactState = 0;
    }
        function contactChange() {
          if (contactState = 0) {
           var contact = document.getElementbyId("main");
           contact.style.display="none";
           contactState = 1;
          }  
          else if (contactState = 1) {
              var contact = document.getElementbyId("main");
              contact.style.display="block";
              contactState = 0;
          }
    }

</script>
```

My code does not seem to work, are there any errors, doing what I want to do?

Comment: Thanks for sharing! What's your question?

Comment: The OP tried to work something out and the approach was flawed. However, Jake did try. Please try to answer the question with a correct approach.

Answer (score 3):

You have some serious issues with the code.

- First of all, your first few lines don't make sense at all.
- Next, `if (contactState = 0)` will set `contactState` to `0`. You want `==`, which *compares* `contactState` to `0`.

Here's what I would try and do:

```
  function contactChange() {
    var contact = document.getElementbyId("main");

    if (contact.style.display == "none") {
      contact.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      contact.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
```

Or if you want to get fancy:

```
  function contactChange() {
    var contact = document.getElementbyId("main");

    contact.style.display = (contact.style.display == "none") ? "block" : "none";
  }
```

Comment: An example I was working on very similar to this answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Bn7dq/

Comment: I think `if (contactState = 0)` will always be `false` because `0 == false`

Comment: I don't like `onclick`s or other inline handlers either, but it's the least evil at this point.

Comment: @DiogoDoreto: Sorry, not sure why I thought an assignment would always return `true`.

Comment: Also, I added `!el.style.display` in the `if` in case it hasn't been set initially.

Comment: Tried that, the stuff in <div id="main"> did not disappear.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Use Firebug/Google Chrome's Inspector to see what's up.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning, not comparing.

Also, wouldn't you want to *flip* the state inside the conditionals? You're setting it to the same value it already is.

Comment: Not to mention `window.onload; { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know already, you should learn how to view your JavaScript console on whatever browser you're using and check if it is logging errors there.

You don't want `contactState = X` in your `if` statements.  You want `contactState == X`.

Not sure what `window.onload` is doing hanging out at the start of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code:

```
> window.onload;
```

That is a reference to the *onload* property of a *window* object. Whatever the value is, it isn't assigned to anything so it is ignored (more or less).

```
> {
```

> ```
>    var contactState = 0;
> ```
>
> }

The `{}` characters enclose a *block statement*, which is usually used with statements like *if*, *for*, *else* and so on. On its own, it does nothing so it can be removed from the above with no effect. That code is identical to:

```
var contactState = 0;
```

which declares the variable *contactState*, when the code is executed, it is assigned a value of the number 0 (zero).

Blender has some comments on the function, which isn't called. Given that it's dealing with DOM elements, likely you intended it to be run when the *load* event occurs, so perhaps you meant to assign the function to the *window.onload* property:

```
window.onload = contactChange;
```

Now the function will be called when the load event occurs, provided it hasn't already occurred when that line of code is executed.